# Index data entered in the smart contract for offchain computation

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to index the data entered in the near protocol smart contract for offchain computation.

How to trigger a new entry of the smart contract in offchain sql database or elasticsearch for real-time data indexing?

I can do that in the frontend, but don't know if it's the right/best method as different users can use different frontend for querying the blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. There is currently not an "event" system in NEAR. So the solution will have to be polling for now.
I would recommend looking at this experimental method:
https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc-experimental#example-of-data-changes

The code contained in that resource is meant to be run in Terminal, similar to running a `curl` command. These types of RPC calls are fairly easy to understand if you look in [near-api-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/near-api-js). For an example of how a NodeJS app *uses* this library which talks to the RPC, I would recommend looking in this directory of `near-shell`:
https://github.com/near/near-shell/tree/master/commands